# Moving by whitespace-delimited word in bash/readline

Tags: bash, readline

In bash line editing (or in any program that uses GNU readline), Meta-f moves to the right by one "word" and Meta-b move to the left by one "word", where a "word" is composed of letters and digits. These are the `forward-word` and `backward-word` commands. (Meta-f can be either the Alt modifier key or a prefix Escape key.)

For example, if I've typed

```
cat /etc/motd
```

then repeatedly typing Meta-b moves the cursor to the `m`, then the `e`, then the `c`.

Is there a command that moves similarly, but by whitespace-delimited words, so `/etc/motd` is a single word?

(I often work with very long file paths, and I'd like to be able to skip over them easily. My workaround is either to type the existing word-move commands repeatedly, or to type ^X ^E to launch an editor.)

In vim, `w` and `b` move forward and back by words, and `W` and `B` move by whitespace-delimited words. I'm looking for something similar.

I've looked through the `readline` documentation, and I suspect the answer is no, but perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: See [What's the shortcut to delete a word "forward" in a unix terminal?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/394418)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `set -o vi` then readline takes `vim` style commands and `w`/`W` and `b`/`B` will have the same word/WORD behavior as in Vim itself. I routinely use `W`/`B` to skip over full paths, urls, etc. when editing the command line. I see from the output of `bind -l` that the readline commands bound to `W` and `B` are `vi-forward-bigword` and `vi-backward-bigword`.

Alternatively, we have `shell-forward-word` and `shell-backward-word`. These commands, per the bash man page, move by *shell metacharacters* which are characters that, *when unquoted, separate words*. Thus, they are a bit less "aggressive" than the `vi-*-bigword` commands but for jumping over long paths they'll almost always do the trick.

So, for example, you could do `bind '"\C-x": shell-backward-word'` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> will behave as described.

Comment: Try it on `"foo bar"` or `$(echo foo bar)` though. It's more like motions based on shell tokens

Comment: Yes, I said "when unquoted" which would not apply to `"foo bar"`, for example. OP specifically mentioned long paths so I thought the `shell-*-word` functions would be of interest despite the "shell metacharacter" aspect if for some reason the `vim-*-word` functions were a problem.

Comment: Good points. I read your answer too quickly,

Comment: Coming back to this several years later. I prefer to use emacs style with readline (ironic, since I use vim as my main editor). I've added these lines to my `$HOME/.inputrc`: `"\eB": shell-backward-word` and `"\eF": shell-forward-word`. With this, Escape-b moves back one alphanumeric word and Escape-B moves back one whitespace-delimited word; likewise for Escape-f and Escape-F.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this:

```
set keymap vi-move
"\e[EMACS~": emacs-editing-mode
set keymap emacs
"\e[VI~": vi-movement-mode
"\ed": "\e[VI~dW\e[EMACS~"
"\ef": vi-fWord
"\eb": vi-bWord
```

To your inputrc or use `zsh` where that's more easily customizable. See [this answer to another Q&A for details](/a/394418).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> seem to be what you are looking for (probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for you).

I came here looking for this, and I took hint from your <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and tried combining with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and it seemed to work for me!

I am on Ubuntu on WSL. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm still using  my custom key bindings `"\eB"` for `shell-backward-word` and `"\eF"` for `shell-forward-word`. I find it a bit easier to type Esc Shift-B than Esc Ctrl-B.